# How to set number of columns based on text length in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[image]I am using recyclerview and GridLayoutManager to display texts in textView .I want to display these items as shown in image 1 .
Requirement of app is enter image description hereIf textview takes 2 lines to display set number of column to 1 else make it 2.
I have tried using GridAutoFitLayoutManager.java from below link,but it didn't work.
https://gist.github.com/omidraha/af3aa017d4ec06342bdc03c49d4b83b1

As of now I have set number of columns to 2. Below is my code
  hotAdapter=new HotAdapter(this,hotItems,this);
        hotRecyclerView.setAdapter(hotAdapter);

```
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

    hotRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) or maybe use [`Chip`s and a `ChipGroup`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). After adding flexbox layout to your project then you can 
set it's direction=row and wrap=wrap.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:flexDirection="row"
app:flexWrap="wrap" >
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    ...
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```